# Stripping lines from multiline textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, string, replace

I have a multiline textbox with text similar to:

```
Tester Testman
None
None
18 Test Court
Upper Test
QLD 4000
```

I'm trying to remove all lines that the word `None`, I've tried the following:

```
private void TextBoxShippingLabel_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxShippingLabel.Text = TextBoxShippingLabel.Text.Replace("None", null);
}
```

However instead of removing the lines this just leaves them empty, so it then looks like the following:

```
Tester Testman


18 Test Court
Upper Test
QLD 4000
```

How can I alter my code to remove the lines with that just contain the word "None" entirely? My desired output would be:

```
Tester Testman
18 Test Court
Upper Test
QLD 4000
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is a multiline textbox named label?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Whoops! Because I rushed the naming structure, thanks for the alert - correcting now.

Comment: I am writing a snippet for you now. Hope I can make it in time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple snippet to do the job:

```
private void UnwantedNoneRemover(TextBox textBox) {
   var lines = textBox.Lines;
   var updatedLines = new List<string>();
   foreach (var line in lines) {
       if (line != "None") { updatedLines.Add(line); }
   }
   textBox.Lines = updatedLines.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This one also won't match `"None"` appearing at the end of the string, by itself on the last line.

Comment: Yeah certainly, I noticed that as well

Comment: @BenVoigt, I have updated the solution for a more readable and "more correct" one

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBoxShippingLabel.Text = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine,TextBoxShippingLabel.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x=>x!="None"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Suposing those "None" lines could contain spaces besides the linebreak, you could use this:

```
Regex regExp = new Regex(@"None[\s]*" + System.Environment.NewLine);

TextBoxShippingLabel.Text = regExp.Replace(TextBoxShippingLabel.Text,"");
```

The regular expression None[\s]* looks for the None word followed by zero or more spaces. Concatenating the System.Environment.NewLine is for removing the linebreak.

Don't forget to add the reference :)

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: Note that this won't remove the last line if it contains (only) the word `"None"`